# Getting values of both status from a same field in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Here am trying to get values from a mysql table with the name lead. and the date range is stored in two variables.

start date is stored in $from and end date is stored in $to.

Status is a field in table lead.

I want to fetch data in the date range and status Hot and status Paid

I tried the following query but its not working as expected. please correct me where am wrong.

```
select * from lead 
WHERE added_on >= '$from' AND added_on <= '$to' AND 
    status='Hot' AND status='Paid'
```

Comment: You say it isn't working as expected. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "IN" to check multiple possible values:

```
SELECT *
FROM `lead`
WHERE
   (`added_on` >= '$from' AND `added_on` <= '$to')
   AND `status` IN ('Hot', 'Paid')
```

Answer (score 3):

Status cannot be hot and paid at the same time.

Status is either "hot" or "paid". You probably want that status "hot" or "paid" and not "hot" and "paid".

```
select * from lead 
WHERE added_on >= '$from' AND added_on <= '$to' AND 
    (status='Hot' or status='Paid')
```

Comment: I think I need new glasses. I wasn't looking at the last clauses.

Comment: Yeah...it cannot be.. it is from a select box in the user. the user can select either Hot or Paid...etc. I want the rows fetched should be between the date range as well as it should contain Hot or Paid either one of the status

Comment: Then you need to pass in status as a parameter. So where status='$status' when sticking to your syntax.

Comment: Both statements should produce the same output! The IN is nicer though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you probably meant to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM lead 
WHERE added_on BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'
AND status IN ('Hot','Paid')
```

Think about your criteria being applied to each record on its own. As the previous poster correctly said "Status cannot be hot and paid at the same time."

Basically, this should return all the records that are either 'Hot' OR 'Paid'.